# XML Validation: cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content found starting with element {..}

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation, xml-validation

I'm trying to validate three XML files, each of which I get the same two errors from. The scheme used for validation was created with Oxygen 18.0 using the scheme generation function (specifically using the three XMLs).

The errors are:

```
cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element '{"http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0":p}'. One of '{"http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0":div}' is expected.
```

and

```
cvc-complex-type.2.4.b: The content of element 'div' is not complete. One of '{"http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0":p}' is expected.
```

They always refer to the following elements enclosed in: ** **

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<text rend="Section" xml:lang="kat">    
        <body>
            <**div** type="Content" n="1">
        <div type="Section" n="1">
            <**p**>
```

I am not sure whether it is due to a faulty scheme (there's a problem preventing me from uploading it right now) or if the the document itself is causing the error. All the documents are however well-formed.
Other sources say that it gets fixed by changing the Default to `elementFormDefault="qualified"` but my XML already contains that. I expect the error to either be associated to `targetNamespace="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0"` (which is part of the XML), or a wrong order of elements. It may have to do with `minOccurs="0"` as well - but as to this point I've read so many threads that I have lost track of a sensible solution.

The obvious is triple checked: the tags are correctly closed at the end

```
            </div></div>    
        </body>
    </text>
```

This is the XML used above: http://pastebin.com/USKZxXM4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The content model for `div` allows it to be empty or to consist of a sequence of `div` and `p`:

```
  <xs:sequence minOccurs="0">
    <xs:element ref="ns1:div"/>
    <xs:element ref="ns1:p"/>
  </xs:sequence>
```

Given that your XML has one `div` element with a `div` child and another `div` element with a `p` child, you instead should make `div`'s content model be a sequence of optional children:

```
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element ref="ns1:div" minOccurs="0"/>
    <xs:element ref="ns1:p" minOccurs="0"/>
  </xs:sequence>
```

if both may be present, or a choice of either:

```
  <xs:choice>
    <xs:element ref="ns1:div"/>
    <xs:element ref="ns1:p"/>
  </xs:choice>
```

if only one may be present.